Proof of Subset Sum from Lattice Reduction
I am currently learning about the subset sum problem and how to solve it using the LLL algorithm. I came across this paper from C. P. Schnorr and M. Euchner "Lattice Basis Reduction Improved Practical
Algorithms and Solving Subset Sum Problems" (https://d-nb.info/1169615635/34). In section [7] of the paper "Solving subset sum problems" they claim that:
Given the lattice basis
\begin{equation} 
B = 
\begin{bmatrix}
2\mathbf{I} & N\mathbf{a} & \mathbf{0} \\
\mathbf{1} & Ns & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & Na_1 & 0\\
0 & 2 & \ldots & 0 & Na_2 & 0 \\
  &   & \ldots &   &      & \\
0 & 0 & \ldots & 2 & Na_n & 0\\
1 & 1 & \ldots & 1 &  Ns & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\in \mathbb{Z}^{(n+1) \times (n+2)}
\end{equation}
Any lattice vector $\mathbf{z}=(z_1, \ldots, z_{n+2}) \in \mathcal{L}(B)$ that satifies: 
\begin{equation} |z_{n+2}|=1, \quad z_{n+1}=0, \quad z_1, \ldots, z_n \in \{\pm1\} \end{equation}
yiels a solution for the subset sum problem
\begin{equation} x_i = \frac{|z_i - z_{n+2}|}{2}, \quad i=1,\ldots,n \end{equation}
The subset sum problem: Find vector $\mathbf{x}$ such that 
\begin{equation} a_1 x_1 + \ldots + a_n x_n = s  \end{equation}
I haven't found any source that provides a mathematical proof on why this is true (why $\mathbf{z}$ yields a solution $\mathbf{x}$) and i was wondering if there are any links to check or any hints i could use to approach it on my own (for example rewrite it as an SVP or CVP problem and do something with that).
